# Writing newline to file opened in binary mode under Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, encoding, newline

When writing a string to a file opened in binary mode in Windows the newline is not encoded for Windows properly.

```
someText = "some\ntext with\nnew lines in\nit"

with open("newFile.txt", "ab") as f:
    f.write(someText.encode("utf-8"))
```

gives me a file that only contains \n as newline character instead of \r\n as would be needed in Windows.

I have previously used the following

```
someText = "some\ntext with\nnew lines in\nit"

with open("newFile.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    f.write(someText)
```

which successfully wrote the file with \r\n as newline in Windows. Unfortunately I cannot use this method as I've had issues with the encoding in the past which led me to change to opening the file in binary mode.
Is there a way to get around this without using

```
someText = someText.replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

before encoding the string as this would break the newline under unix systems?

Comment: What is it you're trying to avoid? If you want windows-style newlines you'll have to stick those `\r`'s in there at some point. What was the encoding issue? Do you really need `\r\n` just because it's windows?

Comment: Try setting the `encoding` parameter in the `open` function like: `with open("newFile.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:` and then use `f.write(someText)`.

Comment: I've had problems with some languages (Turkish for example) when encoding/decoding in utf-8 and writing to file. The solution I settled on was opening the file in binary mode and encode the text explicitly as utf-8. I'm trying to avoid to hardcode the newline replacement from \n to \r\n as I fear this will lead to future problems under unix systems :(

Comment: @VasilisG. This is what I did before and worked fine with the newline encoding. But I had problems with it when working with Turkish unfortunately. This is why I try to find a good solution to it with opening the files in binary mode. Then Turkish is fine but newlines act up :/

Comment: From what I've read, it seems that you have to choose a platform (Unix, Windows) or explicitly trying to find out the platform through code, and acting accordingly.

Comment: So in other words, ignore the systems' default encoding (blame windows) and specify utf8 both when writing and when reading (which you don't need binary mode for, which means you can ignore what newlines should look like)

Comment: @jonatan This is what I did before and then the newline worked fine. But I had trouble with some languages (Turkish for example) which led me to change to doing it this way.  Now Turkish is fine but the newline is not :/ I'm hoping to find a way to do the encoding without hardcoding a replace as I fear this would lead to problems in a unix environment

Comment: You pretty much said that it wasn't using utf8, therefore giving you problems with Turkish. Solution: specify utf8 and you're fine. (What are the alternatives? That you've encountered a python bug? That utf8 doesn't support Turkish? (You're using utf8 now anyway))

Comment: @jonatan Ah, I see that I didn't include the encoding in my example of what I did previously. I tried several ways of doing it, including specifying the encoding when opening the file but opening it in binary was the way I finally got it to work. I'll update my question to make that point clearer

Comment: I don't see why reading the verbatim bytes and decoding from utf8 would be able to read something that opening with utf8 would not. That sounds like saying this is a python bug. Got an example text where there's a difference between those two?

Comment: @jonatan utf-8 definitely supports Turkish :) It was just that the different text 
strings I get is is several different encodings and that the Turkish one acted up (the text in Turkish is not supplied in utf-8 format). opening the file in binary mode was the method that finally worked

Comment: If the file isn't encoded in utf8, then neither method should work since both involve decoding from utf8

Comment: @jonatan It was a while ago I made the change, I'm not sure if I can reproduce it still. I only use notepad++ and it works fine with having \n as newline. But some users are using notepad and there it doesn't work :(

Comment: @jonatan right now I'm only concerned with writing to file, I've worked out how to read the different encodings without trouble. With the reading and writing I have at the moment I am 100% sure I can read the different encodings correctly and save it as utf-8 in all instances. The rest of the code relies on the encoding part so I really don't want to mess with the encoding again and risk the same bugs as previously :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the native new line character(s) by using os.linesep:

```
import os

someText = "some\ntext with\nnew lines in\nit"

with open("newFile.txt", "ab") as f:
    f.write(someText.encode("utf-8").replace("\n", os.linesep))
```

If your text may include both \n and \r\n, best to use a regular expression to do the replace:

```
import os
import re

someText = "some\r\ntext with\nnew lines in\r\nit"
# Matches both \n and \r\n
rgx = re.compile("(\\r)?\\n", flags = re.MULTILINE)

with open("newFile.txt", "ab") as f:
    f.write(rgx.sub(os.linesep, someText.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: This could easily hide subtle bugs and is something that python already does for us. Let's at least find a problem with the built-in behaviour first.

Answer (score 0):

To write strings to a file in append-mode with utf8 encoding and `\r\n` line endings regardless of what system you execute the code on, open it as:

`f = open('filename', mode='a', encoding='utf-8', newline='\r\n')`

You've already decided that the encoding should be utf8 and that is something you can specify when opening the file. Opening in binary mode doesn't help any further with this and appears to be a case of having already decided on a solution and asking about that instead of about the problem that needs solving.