# How to write binary data to next line in a file

Tags: python

I have this below code where i want to write binary data to next line in a file. I've tried to use append binary option but it is also not working.

```
import hashlib


print("*********Sign Up !*********")

user_name=input("Name : ")
user_email=input("Email : ")
user_pass=input("Password : ")

##### hashing #####
hash_pass=hashlib.md5(user_pass.encode('utf8')).digest()
with open("password.txt","ab") as f:
    f.write(hash_pass)
    print("closing the file")
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing newline to file opened in binary mode under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076323/writing-newline-to-file-opened-in-binary-mode-under-windows)